# Display Grid-View Data depending on SelectedItem in DropDownList (asp.net / c#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, dropdownlistfor

I have a Problem in displaying Data depending on Selected Items in a DropDownList. I have a Table with e.g an `equipment`-column and an indexing-column `primekey`. The DDL has just distinct values and i want to show all specific chosen data in a new gridview.

my code looks like this:

```
public partial class _Default : Page
{
    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OLEDB"].ToString());
    OleDbDataAdapter datapter;
    DataSet dset;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            string queryGV = "SELECT * FROM table time > current_timestamp -20  AND EQUIPMENT != 'sth' ORDER BY time DESC";
            string queryDLL1 = "SELECT DISTINCT EQUIPMENT FROM table ORDER BY EQUIPMENT";


            OleDbCommand cmdGV = new OleDbCommand(queryGV, conn);
            OleDbCommand cmdDLL1 = new OleDbCommand(queryDLL1, conn);

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            DataSet DLL1 = new DataSet();

            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmdGV);
            OleDbDataAdapter daDLL1 = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmdDLL1);

            da.Fill(ds);
            daDLL1.Fill(DLL1);

            GridView1.DataSource = ds;
            DropDownList1.DataSource = DLL1;

            GridView1.DataBind();
            DropDownList1.DataBind();
            DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem("Select Teil", "0"));
            GridViewBind();

            conn.Close();
        }
    }

    protected void OnSelectedIndexChanged_DropDownList1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string valtxt = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.ToString();

        if (DropDownList1.SelectedIndex != 0)
        {
            GridViewBind();
        }
    }
}
```

the error occurs in this function:

```
public void GridViewBind()
{
    datapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("select equipment, primekey from PI_EVENT_TABLE where primekey=" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue + "", conn);
    dset = new DataSet();
    datapter.Fill(dset);
    GridView1.DataSource = dset.Tables[0];
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is string format error in below line:

```
datapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("select equipment, primekey from PI_EVENT_TABLE where primekey=" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue + "", conn);
```

use like this

if primekey value is string type

```
datapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("select equipment, primekey from PI_EVENT_TABLE where primekey="' + DropDownList1.SelectedValue + '", conn);
```

or

if primekey value is int type

```
datapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("select equipment, primekey from PI_EVENT_TABLE where primekey=" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString(), conn);
```

Comment: well thanks for your response, but now it says that there is a mistake in this line :   `datapter.Fill(dset);`

do you have an example code which may fits my criteria :/?

Comment: This might be help. Posting another answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OLEDB"].ToString());
    OleDbDataAdapter datapter;
    DataSet dset;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            string queryGV = "SELECT * FROM table time > current_timestamp -20  AND EQUIPMENT != 'sth' ORDER BY time DESC";
            string queryDLL1 = "SELECT DISTINCT EQUIPMENT FROM table ORDER BY EQUIPMENT";


            OleDbCommand cmdGV = new OleDbCommand(queryGV, conn);
            OleDbCommand cmdDLL1 = new OleDbCommand(queryDLL1, conn);

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            DataSet DLL1 = new DataSet();

            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmdGV);
            OleDbDataAdapter daDLL1 = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmdDLL1);

            da.Fill(ds);
            daDLL1.Fill(DLL1);

            GridView1.DataSource = ds;
            DropDownList1.DataSource = DLL1;

            GridView1.DataBind();
            DropDownList1.DataBind();
            DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem("Select Teil", "0"));
            //GridViewBind();

            conn.Close();
        }
    }

    protected void OnSelectedIndexChanged_DropDownList1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string valtxt = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.ToString();

        if (DropDownList1.SelectedIndex != 0)
        {
            GridViewBind();
        }
    }

    private void GridViewBind()
    {
        string query = "select equipment, primekey from PI_EVENT_TABLE where primekey=" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString();
        conn.Open();
        datapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, conn);
        dset = new DataSet();
        datapter.Fill(dset);
        GridView1.DataSource = dset.Tables[0];
        GridView1.DataBind();
        conn.Close();
    }
```

Comment: well thanks mate for your effort, but it doesn´t seem to work this way :/. i don´t know why exactly. If i comment `GridViewBind();` out whithin the `OnSelectedIndexChanged_DropDownList1`-function i don´t get any error, but also no data.


In your version with commenting `GridViewBind();` out of the `Page-Load` i just get ALL the data :/. 
Maybe it helps you to solve this :/

But i just want do get data by selecting it from the DDL.. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public void GridViewBind()
{
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OLEDB"].ToString();
    string selectCommand = "SELECT equipment, primekey FROM PI_EVENT_TABLE WHERE primekey = " 
    + DropDownList1.SelectedValue;

    DataTable table = new DataTable();

    using(var con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
    using(var command = new OleDbCommand(selectCommand, con))
    {
        con.Open();

        try
        {
           table.Load(command.ExecuteReader());
           GridView1.DataSource = table;
           GridView1.DataBind();
        }
        catch(Exception) // place break point here to see if you have exceptions
        {
           throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Also you should rename your gridview and dropdownlist into something more specific like GridViewEquipment or something to that effect

Comment: no you're supposed to have it on true I just thought you had it on false

Comment: yeah i thought so..If i comment `GridViewBind();` out whithin the `OnSelectedIndexChanged_DropDownList1`-function i don´t get any error, but also no data. In your version with commenting `GridViewBind();` out of the Page-Load i just get ALL the data :/. Maybe it helps you to solve this :/ But i just want do get data by selecting it from the DDL.. :)

Comment: place that part of code in try catch block and put a breakpoint in the catch block and tell me what error you get

Comment: the error occurs in this line `datapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("select equipment, primekey from PI_EVENT_TABLE where primekey=" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue + "", conn);` . The table shows different `equipments` (but also doubled ones) and a unique `primekey` next to it. What i want is to select one `equipment` in the DDL and show data referring to it in the gridview. i thought of sth. like: `datapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("select equipment, primekey from PI_EVENT_TABLE where"` **+ DropDownList1.SelectedValue + "=@"** `+ DropDownList1.SelectedValue + "", conn);`
but it also doesn´t work..

Comment: so it's not an actual exception but wrong code for your functionality

Comment: what data is referring to equipment? Do you have another table that's linked via foreign key or no?

Comment: it´s an oracle-databased table with some columns (e.g equipment, and primekey which i chose here to test with). It´s not linked via a foreign Key, just with this Primary Key. Sry, but i´m just a beginner, so i hope you can work with that.

Comment: i really appreciate your effort but now i get an error that current status of the connection is "closed" in line:
`{
                    throw;
                }`

Comment: i fixed this by myself by adding: `if (_conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
      _conn.Open();`

Comment: But now i get another error, i used to have before some time..

`ora-01747 invalid user.table.column table.column or column `